# Should I use \input to organize chapters?

Tags: compiling, files

I want to write simple lecture notes, obviously organized by chapter. I find it most convenient to write the chapter content on the primary tex file, but I've seen other people include separate tex files for each chapter.

Does this make building and compiling more efficient? Everything I'm reading online says that \input is equivalent to copy-pasting the material. If that's the case, what are the main reasons of inputting files? If it's about reducing clutter, why not just click chapter contents out of view?

Comment: From a TeX standpoint `\input` works as if your code was in your main. The true force comes when you use `\include{chapter_x}`  to include each chapter. This you can combine with `\includeonly` to only include certain chapters in the compilation but still have access to all references to the chapters not in the compilation.

Answer (score 4):

No, it doesn't make building and compiling more efficient, but it helps you to better organize your chapters. For lecture notes this might not be an issue, but if you want to reorganize the order of your chapters or subchapters, all that's needed is to rearrange the `\input` commands and recompile.

> If it's about reducing clutter, why not just click chapter contents out of view?

That's not the only advantage. It also makes it much easier to share with collaborators, or to work with a version control system. Finally, the `\includeonly` command really comes in handy at times. (Even though that is for `\include`, not `\input`.)

But none of that is strictly necessary. If you are happy with one humongous file, by all means, go for it.